# A question about numpy "at" function indexation

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/patrk/pyPTE/tree/master/pyPTE) library to compute phase transfer entropy. Long story short, it keeps throwing index-out-of-bounds exception, I isolated a piece of code that does it and it looks pretty much like this:

```
import numpy as np 

idx1 = np.array([7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 8, 5, 5, 5, 8, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 8, 6])
idx2 = np.array([7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 9, 6, 4, 5, 8, 4, 6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 8, 6])

arr = np.zeros([idx1.max()+1, idx2.max()+1])
arr_via_for = np.zeros([idx1.max()+1, idx2.max()+1])

for i, j in zip(idx1, idx2):
    arr_via_for[i, j] += 1
    
np.add.at(arr, [idx1, idx2], 1)
```

What I expect is that arr and arr_via_for should be exactly the same, but they apparently are not, the line

```
np.add.at(arr, [idx1, idx2], 1)
```

throws an exception "IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9" and I cannot find out why. It feels pretty much like I'm missing something really obvious about indexation, but what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know that valid indices for an array with size 9 are the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... 8?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sure, and idx1 array does not contain any numbers exceeding 8. Actually, the arrays are built in the way so that they cannot contain more that idx1.max()+1 elements along the 0th axis: arr = np.zeros([idx1.max()+1, idx2.max()+1])

Comment: I don't get an error (numpy.__version__ = 1.19.1). Just a warning for non-tuple sequence indexing

Comment: it should be a tuple of arrays, `(idx1, idx2)`

Comment: `idx2` has a 9, so the target array should be at least (9,10).  Was there a typo when you first ran this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hpaulj is right (thanks for the help!), the "at" function requires a tuple of arrays instead of an array of arrays in case of the multidimensional first operand. I changed

```
np.add.at(arr, [idx1, idx2], 1)
```

to

```
np.add.at(arr, (idx1, idx2), 1)
```

and it works fine now, and arr and arr_via_for are equal. I did not check it, but I guess the reason was that "array-of-arrays" indexation worked earlier (as FBruzzesi mentioned in comments for 1.19.1 numpy) and do not work now (for 1.23.5, at least). The library I am using was written 4 years ago, so I will just change its code a little bit and hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, array objects index is start from 0, end with the size of the object ***minus 1***. In Python, the error or message or warning state that the size of some arrays or vectors end up with size *n*, but actually you can access to the last item of the list by LIST[(*n* - 1)].

```py
>>> list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> 
>>> # Size of the list
>>> len(list)
9
>>> list_[0]
1
>>> list_[1]
2
>>> list_[8]
9
>>> list_[9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Same to your `numpy` object. `array_[(array_.index("last-item"))] != array_[(len(array_))]`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.array([2,3,4])
np.add.at(arr, [0,1,1,2], 1)
print(arr)
```

```
Output:
[3 5 4]
```

The second argument in my case [0,1,1,2] can't have number 3, as there is no index 3 avaiable in the arr variable.

The above example will add 1 to the number as per index number.